# window.onload sometimes fires before images have their sizes set

Tags: jquery, onload

I'm using some jQuery to reposition images and text to the center of the window in a trivial little slideshow. Naturally, I have to wait until the images have been loaded before doing this, otherwise their size is 0 and the image is placed with the top-left at the middle of the page instead of being offset correctly.

To make sure the images are loaded, I attach the javascript function to $(window).load, like this:

```
$(window).load = start_slideshow()
function center() {
    e = $(this)
    e.css("position","absolute");
    e.css("top", (($(window).height() - e.outerHeight()) / 2) + $(window).scrollTop() + "px");
    e.css("left", (($(window).width() - e.outerWidth()) / 2) + $(window).scrollLeft() + "px");
    return this;
}

function start_slideshow() {
    $(".text").each(center);
    $(".image").each(center);
    $(".slide").each(function() { $(this).hide() } );
    next_slide()
}
```

This works, most of the time. Yet sometimes when refreshing an image will be off-center with its top-left coordinates at the middle, as if it hadn't been loaded by the time the javascrpt was called. I see this maybe one time in five on mobile Safari.

I'm not doing anything special with the images:

```
<div class="image">
    <img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_OxhGU7eVQls/TQ_8RSFptmI/AAAAAAAAAF0/2pKKeDQEK1A/s1600/rainPA_468x409.jpg" />
</div>
```

window.onload is supposed to be *after* all resources are downloaded, so why would the javascript sometimes be executed before an image has its size set correctly? What's the right way to ensure all images are loaded, if window.onload doesn't do this reliably?

Comment: You could try my [jQuery plugin](https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages), it handles this sort of thing well.

Comment: Nice, a way to only wait for the resources I need and not everything including tracking pixels etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
$(window).load(start_slideshow)
```

`start_slideshow()` will execute the function immediately and assigns the return-value of the function to a property "`load`" of `$(window)`

Answer (score -3):

You are using jQuery. You should not be using `$(window).load`.

The correct way to run code on page load using jQuery is:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  ... your on load code here...
});
```

So in your case you would write:

```
function center() {
    e = $(this);
    e.css("position","absolute");
    e.css("top", (($(window).height() - e.outerHeight()) / 2) + $(window).scrollTop() + "px");
    e.css("left", (($(window).width() - e.outerWidth()) / 2) + $(window).scrollLeft() + "px");
    return this;
}

function start_slideshow() {
    $(".text").each(center);
    $(".image").each(center);
    $(".slide").each(function() { $(this).hide(); } );
    next_slide();
}

$(document).ready( function() {
  start_slideshow();
});
```

And as a side note, you should not get into a habit of omitting `;` at the end of statements like you did in your original code. I've fixed that in my snippet.

Comment: ready will fire before the content(including images) is completely loaded. He cannot retrieve the original size of an image before it has finished loading, so he must use (on)load